# Which Elements of Zend are Shipped with PHP?

Tags: php, zend-framework

I'm currently learning PHP (+ MySQL, Javascript, etc.) and looking at the boiler-plate php.ini file I notice the word "Zend" appears once or twice. I've come across the Zend Framework in my research, but does the [latest] PHP distribution ship along with some Zend classes/libraries (if so, presumably due to an acceptance as standard?), or perhaps it provides support in another fashion for Zend in anticipation of a 'typical' or common user-requirement?

Many thanks

Answer (score 4):

This "Zend" refers not to the framework but to the [engine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zend_Engine).  The Zend Engine is the execution engine that powers PHP.  Basically, all the advanced features that are found in PHP are part of the Zend engine that powers the language.

The Zend Framework is a web development framework developed under the auspices of the same company.  There is no other link between them.  No Zend Framework files are installed with PHP by default, though it is very easy to use whatever modules you like from the framework.

Comment: Thank you - that makes perfect sense and clears things up nicely.

Answer (score 0):

No, no php distribution comes with anything from the Zend Framework. You just mix up "Zend (Inc.)" with "Zend Framework". Zend is the corporation behind PHP (namely the Zend engine) and also behind the Zend Framework (of course).

Answer (score 0):

The Zend Framework doesn't come with PHP. The Zend entries you find in the .ini will most likely be to the fact that PHP is built on the engine Zend provided. A little history can be found at [PHP and Zend Engine](http://www.zend.com/en/community/php/)

Answer (score 0):

PHP 1 was built originally by Rasmus.
Two Israely students came by, saw it is good and re-wrote the entire thing. and then re-wrote it again and again (this time with a lot of help of the community) Zend 2,3,4 and 5...

Their names are ZEev and aNDy -> ZEND. and PHP is was built on top of their original engine, which is called by their name (if you have not guessed so by now). 
It will probably remain like that out of respect and due to the fact they still contribute, either by putting in resources from ZEND the company or personally.

That is why you see in php.ini and all through the core of PHP the word ZEND. Nothing to do with ZF.